# How can I calculate seasonal average temperatures for each season in every year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

I need to calculate seasonal average temperatures for each season in every year. The seasons are winter (December, January, February), spring (March, April, May), summer (June, July, August) and autumn (September, October, November). At first I think I need to group the data and then create a loop but I don't know how.

This is how I started my code:

```
#Creating a new dataframe to simplify data

data_winter = data[['DATE', 'TAVG_C']]

#Slicing the column DATE to years and months

data_winter['YEAR_MONTH'] = data['DATE'].str.slice(start=0, stop=6)

#Grouped the data

grouped = data_winter.groupby('YEAR_MONTH')


data_winter
```

And in the picture you can see my Dataframe.
[image]

Comment: Well, seems that my picture didn't show up. The Dataframe has two columns YEAR_MONTH and TAVG_C. TAVG_C values are just temperatures and YEAR_MONTH values are in shape YYYYMM (for example 202111).

Comment: I updated your question. It wasn't formatted.

Comment: I think we can create a year and season code and take the average by grouping. `df['year'] = df['DATE'].dt.year;df['season'] = df['DATE'].dt.month%12 // 3+1;df['TAVG_C'].groupby(['year','season']).mean()`

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
# dictionary for the future replacement of months with seasons
ds = {12: 'winter', 1: 'winter', 2: 'winter', 3: 'spring', 4: 'spring', 5: 'spring',
      6: 'summer', 7: 'summer', 8: 'summer', 9: 'autumn', 10: 'autumn', 11: 'autumn'}

ym = df['YEAR_MONTH'].astype(str)  # if df['YEAR_MONTH'] contains only strings, then you can omit .astype(str)
# make the group indexes - for season and year
g_season = df.assign(Season=ym.str[-2:])['Season'].astype(int).replace(ds)
g_year = df.assign(Year=ym.str[:4])['Year']
# group the df['TAVG_C'] serie by year, season and calculate the mean temp
out = df['TAVG_C'].groupby([g_year, g_season]).mean().reset_index(). \
    rename(columns={'TAVG_C': 'Avg temp.'})
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   Year  Season  Avg temp.
0  1908  winter -25.388889
1  2020  autumn   7.111111
```